# dought in returning array and int data type from function in c

Tags: c, function

code 1

---

```
    main()
{
    int i ,a[5];
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    yo(a);
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",a[i]);
    }
}
void yo(int a[5])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        a[i]=a[i]+1;
    }
}
```

---

in the above code with out returning values(i am returning void data type in function) the array 'a' is getting updated in main function but when i don't use array and use normal int data type the values does'nt get updated  see code 2

---

```
main()
{
    int a;
    a=50;
    yo(a);
    printf("%d",a);
}
void yo(int z)
{
    z=150;
}
```

Comment: @ryyker "work" is a relative term. Neither *crash*. The OP is essentially asking about the difference between passing an array and a non-array, and why the former appears to pass by address, while the latter clearly passes by value. It is also something any [decent book on the C language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?s=1|5.8834) and any of a thousand tutorial websites cover in-detail.

Comment: @ryyker with or without a proper prototype, the value of `a` in `main()` is **not** updated upon execution and return of `yo()` in code2. I concur with you, both need proper prototyping, regardless.

Comment: @WhozCraig - my bad.  I just re-checked.  You are right.

Answer (score 2):

It is because the array `a[]` is being passed as a pointer, not a copy of the array, and the array is modified directly. If you declare the function as

```
void yo(int *a)
```

that will work in exactly the same way. But if you pass a single `int` such as

```
void yo(int a) {
    a += 1;
}
```

the function only receives a *copy* of the `int` and it does not affect the caller. To affect the variable passed, you would have

```
void yo(int *a) {
    *a += 1;
}
```

And guess what? That's the same declaration as I put earlier when you pass an array. When you pass a pointer, it can be treated as an array, or as a single value - namely an array of length 1.